# My Docker Desktop service can't start in the service. and app Docker Desktop can't start

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

all
my Docker Desktop have been working very well for a long time, but after I reboot my office PC, I can't start the Docker Desktop. double click the Docker Desktop, I can see it in the process list for a second, then quit.

then I input docker info in powershell, it prints

PS C:> docker info
Client:
Context:    default
Debug Mode: false
Plugins:
buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc., v0.7.1)
compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc., v2.2.1)
scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.14.0)

Server:
ERROR: error during connect: In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run with elevated privileges to connect.: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/info": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
errors pretty printing info

then I open the service, I see Docker Desktop service can't be started.
it said,

windows could not start the Docker Desktop Service service on Loal Computer.
Error1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

I once tried to uninstall the Docker Desktop, however this process Docker Desktop can't be executed. It quits soon. I can't install and uninstall the Docker Desktop, and can't start it.

could anybody help me? thanks a lot!

Comment: It seems you are using windows system, try running the docker desktop with admin rights. Start menu , docker -> right click -> Run as admin.

Comment: yes,  I am using windows system. I tried, it didn't work.